# Python list initialized with question mark

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
word = ['?']
```

What does the above line initialize in python?

Is that a special type of initialization?

Comment: did you event try it and see what it does?

Comment: I did . It just had the '?' as an element. Is that it?

Comment: so you didn't even have to ask here then

Answer (score 4):

It's initializing a list with a `'?'` string as its only element.